# Uninstalled windows, now bootmgr is missing

Tags: boot, kernel, uninstall

I enjoyed using Ubuntu for the past few weeks and decided to uninstall Uindows using the "OS-Uninstaller Graphical Tool". Now I get the error `bootmgr is missing`. When I try to use the DVD from the Boot Menu, it shows

```
kernel panic - not syncing : VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(2,0)
```

I'm new to Linux and any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something went awry with your uninstall! ;)

My guess is that when you uninstalled Windows, it took part of Grub (Ubuntu's default Bootloader) with it. I've ran into similar issues, though I'm not sure it's exactly the same.

To fix my issues when I lost my bootloader, I started up a LiveCD/USB and then chrooted into my HDD installation of Ubuntu. From there, I ran `update-grub` and from that point on, it worked fine again.

The Accepted Answer [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) Gives a Step By Step Explanation of the Above.

== Another Thought ==

It's also possible that when you uninstalled Windows, some configurations with grub needed changed, ie the sector that it boots from ( hd(0,1) etc ).

Comment: Thanks for responding! However, using the live CD/USB is how it goes into the kernel panic. Therefore I can't get past step 1 of the instructions linked. Solutions I've found online don't involve both the bootmgr and kernel panic.

Comment: lol, that doesn't make a ton of sense to me. Using the LiveUSB, it shouldn't panic. Are you 100% sure that it's not instead going straight to the HDD, thus bypassing booting the LiveUSB?

Comment: I've even selected the CD/DVD drive (I've tried usb and dvd by this point) in the boot menu. Both ways I get the same kernel panic.

Comment: When you say "boot menu", are you referencing a purple screen that has entries like "Ubuntu", "MemTest86+", etc, or a black screen that says "HDD", "CD/DVD", "USB", "Network"?

Comment: The black screen, it then kernel panics or goes to the purple screen. From the purple screen I've tried "try ubuntu w/o install" and actually installing, both of which end in a kernel panic.

Comment: hmmm. interesting. I've never ran into that issue. I'll think about it, but I don't know of anything else off the top of my head. Can you boot from any other LiveVariants, like gparted live?

Comment: Thanks for the effort, at least I know I'm not going crazy lol.

Comment: So you're using BIOS Boot Menu to start your computer from CD/DVD or USB instead of internal HDD, and you face this problem. In that case it's very likely that there's a problem with the ISO file downloaded (have checked its integrity using MD5 Checksum file?) or with the DVD (or USB) written - or both. Otherwise you should have been able to boot your computer normally into an **Ubuntu Live Session** and run `sudo update-grub` in Terminal to resolve your Grub bootloader problem.

Comment: Thanks, turned out being a problem with my image processing tool. Just used the default one for windows 7 and everything is fine.